# css нюансы и тонкости

Tags: css

В чём отличие

```
.data div {…}
```

от

```
 .data > div{…}
```

Вроде и там и там выберет в итоге div внутри .data? или я чет не так понимаю?

Comment: Второй селектор выбирает только непосредственного потомка, а первый выбирает также «внуков» и «правнуков» и так далее, проверьте на коде типа `<article class="data"><div>1</div><section><div>2</div></section></article>`

Comment: Спасибо. А чо в ответ не поставил.? Я б закрыл вопрос